# Java BB 907 invalid COD. HTTP error 404: not found - using AWS beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, blackberry, download

Hi there i can see the error is most familiar out in many blackberry forums even there we couldn't find any solution for file(.jad, .jar) download error (907 invalid COD. HTTP error 404: not found), why is this happens because i cannot sort out the issue from my mobile side, may the problem persist from server??
Please clear my doubt because stuck in this process for so long ..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is an old problem, related to the size of a cod file.

If your cod file is longer than 64Kb, then rapc compiler makes so called sibling cod files with 64Kb or less size, packed into one cod file.

So, if you have one big cod file, let say `myapplication.cod`, rename it to "myapplication.zip".

Then unpack it. And you will get a set of cod files.

Now, delete `myapplication.zip` and place all of cod files from this archive along with jad file, to your server.

Your jad file already has references to all these small cod files.